# Problems trying to compile

Tags: r, miktex

I'm trying to compile a document in R studio but when i do it it gave me a error.

Error: LaTeX failed to compile Ejercicio-1-Econometría.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips.

After that I go to the debugging site and I'm trying to follow the steps but when I use `tinytex::tlmgr_update()` I have the follow error

```
tlmgr update --all --self
```

> Error in system2("tlmgr", args, ...) : '"tlmgr"' not found

So I don't know what to do, please some help

I don't know much about R studio, so I do the steps in the page of debugging an also try to update packages, update MikTex console but nothing work.

Comment: The command is `tlmgr_update` with an underscore, not `tlmgr update` with a space.